# I want to know how to request POST using REST API. (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, api, authorization

I would like to receive a token using http post based on the image below.
I wrote it like the bottom code, but it doesn't work well. What should I do?

```
 func login() {
    
    let username = "TestID"
    let password = "TestPW"
    let loginString = "\(username):\(password)"

    guard let loginData = loginString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) else {
        return
    }
    let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedString()
            
    let param = "id=0000&password=1234&password2=1234&grantType=password"
    let paramData = param.data(using: .utf8)
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://TestUrl.com")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("Basic \(base64LoginString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.setValue(String(paramData!.count), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    
    request.httpBody = paramData
    
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
        print(response!)
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
            print(json)
        } catch {
            print("error")
        }
    })
    
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please describe in more detail what do you mean by "it doesn't work well"? What is the server response and what errors are you getting?

Comment: @VadimBelyaev The API returns only errors. They want me to get a token issued using Oauth2.0, but I asked if I was approaching it wrong.. TT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on image of the API, it looks like you re sending `Authentication` header correctly. However it seems the body data is expected as JSON object:

```
{
    "id": 0000,
    "password": 1234,
    "password2": 1234,
    "gratType": "password"
}
```

So you need to create a `Codable` structure:

```
struct LoginData: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let password: Int
    let password2: Int
    let gratType: String
}
```

And then you convert it to JSON:

```
let loginData = LoginData(id: 0, password: 1234, password2: 1234, gratType: "password")
request.httpBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(loginData)
```

Note that I created this structure based on your example, which shows `id`, `password` and `password2` fields as numeric fields (not Strings), which is a bit weird to me, I would expect at least password fields to be Strings. Also `gratType` is potentially misspelled (should be `grantType`?). But that's something you can adjust later.